# PHP Ansi to UTF-8

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8, ansi, mojibake

I'm trying to create a script in PHP for converting some files to UTF-8. I have a file in Greek, where Notepad++ indicates that it ahs "ANSI" encoding. When I upload it to the server, it detects it's encoding as UTF-8 (something wrinf i think). Then when I convert it's contents to UTF-8 with utf8_encode () and download the new file, the characters are messed up. I tried to remove the BOM with PHP and the result was the same. I tried to remove the BOM with PHP without converting the file to UTF-8 but the file remained in ANSI encoding, without messed up characters. How can I fix that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove BOM, then do:

```
$file = file_get_contents('file.php');
$file = iconv('greek-charset','UTF-8', $file);
file_put_contents('file.php', $file);
//ta-da!
```

Change `greek-charset` to correct name of charset (maybe `Windows-1253`).

Comment: where can i find the charset?

Comment: @Paris: You can find an extended list of available charsets here: http://www.gnu.org/software/libiconv/ - the concrete install might differ, however that list is a good orientation.

Comment: use CP1251 from 'greek-charset'